# Vought and non-white races in The Boys

Tags: the-boys

Why would Vought make other than white superheroes with it's racist background?

This is obviously not addressing "terrorists" as there is clear reason for that. It is about A-Train, Shockwave, Black Noir etc.

Comment: Ideally people would explain their downvotes.

Comment: My understanding is that Black Noir's race is not disclosed.

Comment: @Accumulation with my first question here I have been told no spoiler alerts needed. That is all I can say if you do not wish to know more. If you do, simple search will do, multiple spoiler articles talk about this.

Comment: You've seen their company-obsession with PR and marketing, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the founder of Vought was a literal Nazi he is long dead and no longer in charge  (remember the founder was already an adult male by the time Hitler rose to power). Over the years their higher ranking staff members have switched out with new ones that climbed the ranks, people who did not share the founders racial supremacy ideas but were more focused on money.

And just  like in Real Life, movies and similar media are being pushed by an inclusive agenda that represents everybody in a ploy to make more money. And at this point Vought is little more then a media company that houses weapons of mass destruction.

At the point of the show the company itself is run by Stan Edgar, a man who is portrayed by an actor who is Italian-African.

Comment: Yep, kind of what I was thinking, makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that the origins of the technology used by Vought are Nazi, the company has clearly become run with an American Nationalist perspective. And is run by an arch capitalist, Stan Edgar, who is obviously not white.

Certainly, at least in Series 1, the company is portrayed as villainous because of its arch money-grabbing capitalist orientation, not because of racism. The superheros exploit American patriotism to make money and jealously guard the wholesome american image of their heros even when they commit heinous acts.

Series 2 adds some extra nuance with the revelation that Stormfront is an actual surviving Nazi experiment. But, as she explains to Homelander (s2:e6) while trying to get him onside after annoying him:

> We are in a war for the *culture*. But we can fight back.

Implying that she has pivoted to a general anti-foreginer campaign (with potentially deliberate echos of some Trumpian rhetoric). This is fairly clear from some of the public speeches she and Homelander give in their attempt to justify compound V and to undermine the campaign against it. So she now fights for American culture not for the exact same goals as the original Nazis.

Arguably, Naziism is defined by the groups it *hates* (with a focus on the Jews) and extreme nationalism not by general racism. Historically anti-jewish arabs fought alongside Nazis so the ideology was flexible enough to pivot against their most hated "enemies" without being *generally* racist against all non-germans. Since Vought is making tons of money from US-loving minorities it isn't too much of a stretch to see even their Nazi past allowing them to find a different hate group to use to promote their corporation. though, as the final episode of series 2 makes clear, she has not shed all of her innate prejudices even if she has suppressed them for short term gain.